# How to have flexible nested initializers?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, initialization, constants

Suppose I have this code:

```
// These struct should never be modified after the fact.

typedef struct keyvalue {
  const char *identifier;
  const void *udObj;
} keyvalue;

typedef struct my_object {
  const char *name;
  const keyvalue *kv;
} my_object;

// Later, I want to use it as follows... (no workies)

const my_object mo = {
  .name = "Stigma",
  .kv = {
    { "test", test },
    { "test2", test2 },
    { NULL, NULL }
  }
};

// I also want to support syntax like: (no workies, either)

const key_value custom_kv[] = {
  { "test", test },
  { NULL, NULL }
};

const my_object mo = {
  .name = "Stigma",
  .kv = custom_kv
};
```

Sadly, I can't seem to get this to work. The error I am getting when compiling the former g++ is as follows:

```
error: invalid initializer for ‘const keyvalue my_object::kv [0]’
```

The secondary gets a similarly fuzzy error message:

```
error: too many initializers for ‘const key_value [0]
```

I've tried a to add another layer of pointer to *kv, but I don't honestly think that's the route I ought to be taking: that was the desperation kicking in. I have half a mind to tear out the const specifiers, but that would be defeat!

How do I properly declare my structures and struct initializations to have the functionality / meaning I am looking for? Preferably without copying the entire array in the process, since that'd be yucky.

(And yes, I am aware this is C-style code, and I have a C++ tag. This codebase is very confused, being compiled with g++ but still wanting to stick to C patterns for silly reasons that don't matter for this question. The situation is as it is and I am not in a position to change that.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem with the first Approach is that you can't assign an initializer for an Array to a pointer. You could convert it to a template to use Arrays of different sizes. But then you'll get some Problems with your second example. I have somehow a solution for you. What about this:

```
typedef struct keyvalue {
  const char *identifier;
  const void *udObj;
} keyvalue;

template<int size>
struct my_object {
  const char *name;
  const struct keyvalue kv[size];
};

// You Need to define the size of the inner array

const my_object<3> mo = {
  .name = "Stigma",
  .kv = {
    { "test", test},
    { "test2", test2},
    { NULL, NULL }
  }
};


const struct keyvalue custom_kv[] = {
  { "test", test},
  { NULL, NULL }
};

// Here you Need to use the initializer list as follows. There is no way around

const my_object<2> mo2 = {
  .name = "Stigma",
  .kv = {
    { custom_kv[0].identifier, custom_kv[0].udObj },
    { custom_kv[1].identifier, custom_kv[1].udObj }
  }
};
```

Comment: It isn't really what I am looking for; the kind of duplication in your second example isn't what I was hoping for. I think the resulting code does not gain me any of the simple-to-read-and-use benefits I was looking for. It seems like I'm ending up removing the const for the array and going with a manual assignment there. But since your answer does kind of solve it (just not how I can use it and be willing to live with to boot!) I will accept your answer. :)